# How to resolve error pipe could not be found in angular 11

Tags: pipe, angular11

I'm not using pipes for the first time, but now I'm trying to use safe pipe which I created in a separated folder "pipes" with `PipesModule` as below
this is the pipe class:

**safe.pipe.ts**

```typescript
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeResourceUrl, SafeScript, SafeStyle, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    @Pipe( {
        name: 'safe'
    } )
    export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    
        constructor ( protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) { }
    
        public transform ( url: any ) {
            return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( url );
        }
    }
```

and this is the module file **pipes.module.ts**

```typescript
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { SafePipe } from './safe.pipe';
    
    
    
    @NgModule( {
        declarations: [
            SafePipe
        ],
        exports: [
            SafePipe
        ],
        imports: [
            CommonModule
        ]
    } )
    export class PipesModule { }
```

and I imported the PipesModule in the component module that I want to use pipe in,

```typescript
    @NgModule( {
        declarations: [ GenerateContractComponent ],
        imports: [
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            NgxMaskModule,
            PipesModule
        ]
    } )
```

Then used pipe in HTML as this:

```html
    <iframe width="100%" style="height:-webkit-fill-available" [src]="pdfURL | safe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but still get the error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0302: The pipe 'safe' could not be found!
> Please can anyone help??

Comment: Try to remove CommonModule from PipesModule

Comment: @feihoa No, This didn't help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have similar problem and my solution was to simply **restart the server**.

If the above does not work, close the IDE and restart the project. It may be an issue with cached files

If this doesn't work also clear browser cache and reload you app

From the below [Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ehvths?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) Your approach is correct and should work

Comment: Yes, I did that, and now It's working, Thank you